# Get WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest() in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grails

I can access  `WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest()` on localhost(everything works fine). But if I try to deploy the .war file on the tomcat server I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
        at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131)
        at org.grails.web.util.WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest(WebUtils.java:442)
        at org.grails.web.util.WebUtils$retrieveGrailsWebRequest.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
        at pos.kasse.session.SessionService.getCurrentUser(SessionService.groovy:25)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MethodMetaProperty$GetBeanMethodMetaProperty.getProperty(MethodMetaProperty.java:76)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePogoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePogoPropertySite.java:85)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:299)
```

Comment: What version of Grails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access `request` and/or `session` without referencing any holders or referencing `WebUtils`.

```
// grails-app/services/lastone/DemoService.groovy
package lastone

import grails.web.api.ServletAttributes

class DemoService implements ServletAttributes {

    def someMethod() {
        // From here you can access the
        // session and/or request properties
        // directly...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem was the springsecurity-plugin. You have to use the request/session from there like:

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolder as SRH
SRH.request.session
```

Comment: This is not the best way to do this.  The best approach will depend on knowing which version of Grails you are using.

Comment: Grails Version 3.3.9 - What would be better then?